# dplyr & subset: wrong way to remove rows

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, row, subset

I'm trying to remove rows in my dataset according with specific values in 2 columns, but it seems that i'm setting it in the wrong way.

Here a sample of dataset

```
   nquest  nord   sex anasc  ireg   eta staciv studio    ID tpens
    <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int>
 1    173     1     1  1948    18    72      3      5     1  1800
 2   2886     1     1  1949    13    71      1      5     2  1211
 3   2886     2     0  1952    13    68      1      6     3  2100
 4   5416     1     0  1958     8    62      3      3     4   700
 5   7886     1     1  1950     9    70      1      5     5  2000
 6  20297     1     1  1960     5    60      1      3     6  1200
 7  20711     2     1  1944     4    76      1      2     7  2000
 8  22169     1     0  1944    15    76      4      2     8   600
 9  22276     1     1  1949     8    71      2      5     9  1200
10  22286     1     1  1950     8    70      1      2    10   850
11  22286     2     0  1956     8    64      1      2    11   650
12  22657     1     0  1951    13    69      1      7    12  2400
13  22657     2     1  1946    16    74      1      5    13  1500
14  23490     1     0  1937     5    83      2      5    14  1400
15  24147     1     1  1948     4    72      1      7    15  1730
16  24147     2     0  1958     4    62      1      5    16  1600
17  24853     1     1  1957    13    63      1      3    17  2180
18  27238     1     1  1952    12    68      1      3    19  1050
19  27730     1     1  1939    20    81      1      2    20  1470
20  27734     1     1  1947    20    73      1      2    21  1159
```

I want to get a dataset in which are exluded all the rows where the values of `tpens` are greater than 2000 if `ireg` = 13 ( I need to maintan all the other values of `tpens` and `ireg` if `ireg` is different than 13).

I have tried

```
new <- subset(data, data$ireg == 13 & data$tpens <= 2000)
```

But it is wrong, because even if `tpens` are now lower than 2000, it gives me a dataset with only `ireg` == 13. I need to maintain all the other values of `ireg` ( and then the `tpens` values linked to them) actually.

I also tried

```
new <-data [!(data$ireg == 13 & data$tpens <= 2000),]
```

But it is the same. Even using `filter` of dplyr, it seems I'm not able to set the conditions in the proper way

How can I remove the rows that satisfy specific conditions on 2 columns at the same time, but without delete all the other things?

I hope I was able to explain myself

Comment: If you want to use `dplyr`, `filter` is the `dplyr` version of base R's `subset`

Comment: hi @Maël and thank for the answer. I've tried also with filter, but actually it seems I'm not able to set the condition in the proper way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset` or `filter` *keeps* the rows where the conditions are matched. So, you rather want the inverse selection:

```r
filter(data, !(ireg == 13 & tpens > 2000))
```

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen does your code give a different output tha this? I'm new in this kind of things

Comment: @io_boh it would have produced a different outcome for rows with `ireg == 13` and `tpens == 2000` exactly, but Mael has edited now and they should be precicesly equivalent.  I recommend you tick his answer as accepted if it gives you the expected output.

Comment: ok @PaulStaffordAllen thank! I'm going to accept his answer, but please do not delete yours if it works fine and it is just another way to do it ... I've notice that some users remove their answers if they are not accepted... It is a pity, I used to review my past questions to study the how to code and sometimes some answers are disappeared

Comment: Oh no, I'll leave it up, I just think his way is better so I'd rather see that one at the top.

Comment: @io_boh You could also do `subset(dat, !(ireg == 13 & tpens > 2000))`.

Comment: thank @jay.sf , I will keep in mind also this option

Answer (score 2):

```
data %>% filter((ireg == 13 & tpens <= 2000) | ireg != 13)
```